# When is the Window.SourceInitialized event raised

Tags: wpf, interop, window, pinvoke

Can I guarantee the `Window.SourceInitialized` event will always be raised before the `Window.Loaded` event?
I need the `HwndSource` object for further processing in my **Window.Loaded event handler** and I'm not sure if this will always be available by then

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the sequence of events you can expect (it should occur before Loaded):

- http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/07/30/613-window-event-sequence/

If you want to double-check, or don't trust getting the SourceInitialized event...then you can try and obtain the HwndSource yourself....to see if it's connected.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/digitalnetbizz/archive/2007/03/09/presentationsource.aspx