# Difference between OnInitialized and OnSourceInitialized in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to add global hotkeys in WPF.

```cs
        var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        var handle = helper.Handle;
        var source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle);
```

When I put this piece of code in `OnInitialized` override method, it returns the value `0` for `handle` variable and fails in `HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle)`.

But, when I put it in `OnSourceInitialized` override method, it returns some random value for `handle` variable and works fine in `HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle)`.

I was trying to understand why is this the behavior.
What is the difference between OnInitialized and OnSourceInitialized in WPF?

Comment: Here is a question about source initialiazed. The answer contains interesting links to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077707/when-is-the-window-sourceinitialized-event-raised

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `FrameworkElement.Initialized` event is raised when a `FrameworkElement` (a WPF element) is initialized.
[Here in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> This event will be raised whenever the `EndInit` or
>   `OnVisualParentChanged` methods are called. Calls to either method could
>   have come from application code, or through the Extensible Application
>   Markup Language (XAML) processor behavior when a XAML page is
>   processed.

Than means, this event is raised when the XAML tree is processed. It can be raised for any `FrameworkElement`, including a `Window`.

The `Window.SourceInitialized` event is raised when the underlying Win32 window handle becomes available. It is only raised on a `Window`. You can read more in the [`HwndSource` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.hwndsource?view=netframework-4.7.2).

That is the explanation why you get a valid handle in the `Window.SourceInitialized` event handler and an invalid handle (0) in the `FrameworkElement.Initialized` event handler.